# Remove all characters prior to last character

Tags: php

Consider the following string:

```
Hello World
```

My aim is to remove all the characters prior to the last character ("d"), excluding the last character.

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this in PHP?

Comment: show an example of the result you wish to accomplish

Comment: `substr('Hello World', -1);` or PHP7 `$str[-1]` - https://3v4l.org/FF07h

Comment: Seems, you just want the last char..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) in php

```
<?php 
$str = "Hello World";
echo substr($str, -1);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get the last

```
 substr("Hello World", -1); // returns "d"
```